# optparse won't pass default values

Tags: python, optparse

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why this doesn't work:

```
import optparse, sys
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-i", help="Input File", dest="input_file", metavar=" ")
parser.add_option("-x", help="Image Width (default is %default)", dest="image_width" default="1920", metavar="WIDTH")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

print options.input_file
print image_width
```

When it gets to "print image_width" it gives me a "name is not defined" error.
If I run the same script with the -h option, then the displayed help DOES show the default value.  So it is working, but it's not!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW:

```
dest="image_width" default="1920",
```

...is missing a comma.